# Google Scripts getting the day of the week

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to convert some excel VBA (that worked like a charm) into Google scripts, but I'm getting stuck handling the dates.

I am pulling the date from a cell in Sheets and then testing if it's the weekend or not. The cell has been formatted as a date and I've declared it a date()

```
var DayOpen = date();
DayOpen = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Basics').getRange(1, 1).getValue();
if (DayOpen.getDay() > 6) ...
```

However, I don't seem to be getting an integer from this.  I'm totally new to Google scripts, but this is giving me a headache.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare `DayOpen` as a date.

[FWIW, `var DayOpen = date();` means the variable is set to the value returned by the function `date()`]

The following should do the trick:

```
function sampleScript() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var DayOpen = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Basics').getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  Logger.log(DayOpen); // Should log a date if A1 has one.
  Logger.log(DayOpen.getDay());  // Should log day of the week as an integer
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  I copied your code and I get this error:
"TypeError: DayOpen.getDay is not a function"
I have the code exactly as you've typed: "DayOpen.getDay()"

I don't get it...  :-(

Comment: Aaahh ok, so... perhaps the thing that's tripping me up here is this:
I want to increase the DayOpen' variable by 1 day at a time and I'm using

var day1 = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

and then I'm adding `code` DayOpen = DayOpen + day1
But that's when I get the function error... so how can I increase the day by 1 correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
This is what I should have done to increment the day by 1:

```
DayOpen.setDate(DayOpen.getDate() + 1
```

This gets the date, adds one and then sets the date..

Comment: Irrelevant to the actual question asked here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var DayOpen = new Date(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Basics').getRange(1, 1).getValue()).getDay();
if (DayOpen==0 || DayOpen==6) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('It\'s the weekend.')
}
```